# What services and activities are really required for Urban Airship Android push notifications?

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I have some doubts about what is really required for the `Urban Airship` Android push notifications.

I removed the following lines, given in the [doc](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html), from my `AndroidManifest.xml` because I do not seem to need these services and activity, but get the errors shown below.

When running the app everything seems to work properly, but I'd like to be sure that I can ignore these errors.

Can these lines be safely removed if the corresponding activity and services are not needed?

**Lines removed from `AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService" android:label="Event Service" />
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionService" />
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService" />

<activity
    android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.my.package.MainActivity"
    android:exported="false">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.my.package.MainActivity" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.SHOW_LANDING_PAGE_INTENT_ACTION" />

        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Errors returned**

```
MyAppName - UALib﹕ AndroidManifest.xml missing required service: com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService
MyAppName - UALib﹕ AndroidManifest.xml missing required service: com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService
MyAppName - UALib﹕ AndroidManifest.xml missing required service: com.urbanairship.actions.ActionService
MyAppName - UALib﹕ AndroidManifest.xml missing activity with an intent filter for action com.urbanairship.actions.SHOW_LANDING_PAGE_INTENT_ACTION, category android.intent.category.DEFAULT, and data with scheme http.  Landing page action may not function properly.
MyAppName - UALib﹕ AndroidManifest.xml missing activity with an intent filter for action com.urbanairship.actions.SHOW_LANDING_PAGE_INTENT_ACTION, category android.intent.category.DEFAULT, and data with scheme https Landing page action may not function properly.
```

Comment: hi..@jul, right now i have seen thier official page and they have given nice document for integration. had u gone through that?

Comment: I did, but it's not clear to me what are the minimal requirements.

Comment: Just because a service, activity, or receiver is listed in the manifest does not mean its going to be actively taking up resources. It only allows those components to be started from an intent. There is really no reason to try to strip it out.

Answer (score 2):

you need to follow below links.

for documentation: http://docs.urbanairship.com/

For intigration (Android and IOS) : https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push

Please be careful of requirement of cordova version and phonegap version according to doc while implement above urbanairship plugin.
hope it helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned services are mandatory.

But that activity is needed **only if you are using Landing Page** to send the notification.

Notification can be send in different ways using UrbanAirship. MessageCenter, Landing Page or URL can be used for sending the notification. The one send through 
Landing Page will not be saved in the database and will be lost once it is viewed.